# PHP email : Weird chars

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email

I'm looking for a nice way to send mails on my site.

I've been struggling for hours now, because i randomly get chars in my mails and sometimes it breaks the HTML.

I'm using codeigniter (V3.0) but it was the same deal when i was in 2.x.

Here's the most important part of my code :

```
$configs = array(
    'protocol'  =>  'smtp',
    'smtp_host' =>  'smtp.my_server.fr',
    'smtp_user' =>  'contact@my_server.fr',
    'smtp_pass' =>  'my_pass',
    'smtp_port' =>  'my_port',
    'mailtype'  =>  'html',
    '_bit_depths' => 'base64',
    '_encoding' =>  'base64'
);

$this->CI->load->library("email", $configs);
$this->CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->CI->email->to($mail);
$this->CI->email->from("contact@my_server.fr", "My server");
$this->CI->email->subject( $objet );
$this->CI->email->message( $mail_html)) );
$this->CI->email->send();
```

I just don't get it ... I'm pretty sure, if i was able to send mail in base_64 it would be okay but i'm missing something !

If someone have any idea about that, i would really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a mailing software I used in the past. It would break Russian text from time to time. The encoding it used was 7bit quoted printable, and per what I concluded it had problems with certain sequence of utf-8 characters. The solution was to add a `<span></span>` just prior to problematic parts in the email. So for example instead of `"Sóme spécial téxt"` (which would show garbled: `Sóme sp文~ cial téxt`), I would have html look like this: `Sóme sp<span></span>écial téxt` and it would show properly. That of course only works if you are able to send yourself a test email

Comment: I do have span (not for that use but i have). It won't solve my problem because random chars pop over the whole html document and even breaks the div, span, p, etc ....

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same problem, i found an amazing php library on GitHub.
This saved my day : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Really simple to use and mails are well encoded ...

Hope this help some day,

cheers